# MySql SELECT with GROUP or SUBQUERY with temporary tables? Then ordered TWICE ? How?

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Title of question is my thoughts of the solution to the following problem but of course i do not want to limit your answers to that.

Description of database:

Table: Players

Columns: Player_id (integer primary key indexed), Team_id (integer), Player_name (text), Player_points (integer), Player_status (ENUM 'Ok','NotOk')

I want to have the 5 players with most points for each of these Team_id's (1,2,3).

Rows 1-5 team 1, rows 6-10 team 2, rows 11-15 team 3. Players ordered by points and then by status for each team, in one query (CORRECTION: or more queries if there is no choice).

row 1-5 (as you can see for team_id 1):

- 2,1,Jordan,10000,Ok
- 8,1,Pippen,9000,Ok
- 5,1,Rodman,9000,Ok
- 9,1,Grant,9000,NotOk  (as you can see they are sorted by points, and    then by status)
- 1,1,Parish,5000,Ok

row 6-10 (for team_id 2):

- 14,2,Ewing,8000,NotOk
- 11,2,Starks,7000,Ok
- 10,2,Oakley,7000,NotOk
- 19,2,Harper,6000,Ok
- 13,2,Smith,5000,Ok

row 11-15 (for team_id 3):

- 29,3,Bird,9000,Ok
- 28,3,Rivas,8000,NotOk
- 21,3,Paxson,7000,Ok
- 20,3,Shaw,7000,NotOk
- 22,3,Lohaus,7000,NotOk

I'm seeking a solution with good performance. Tables will have thousands of data, but Team_id's will be just 3 (NBA teams/players here are just for demo purposes)

Comment: The infamous greatest-n-per-group (hopefully this triggers some related questions) that MySQL has such poor support for. An order-by (3 way on team, points, status) would take care of the rest.

Comment: oh, god... there is a tag named "greatest-n-per-group"? This can't be good...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT Player_id, Team_id, Player_name, Player_points, Player_status FROM Players WHERE Team_id = 1 ORDER BY Team_id, Player_points DESC, Player_status DESC LIMIT 5
UNION ALL
SELECT Player_id, Team_id, Player_name, Player_points, Player_status FROM Players WHERE Team_id = 2 ORDER BY Team_id, Player_points DESC, Player_status DESC LIMIT 5
UNION ALL
SELECT Player_id, Team_id, Player_name, Player_points, Player_status FROM Players WHERE Team_id = 3 ORDER BY Team_id, Player_points DESC, Player_status DESC LIMIT 5
)
ORDER BY Team_id, Player_points DESC, Player_status DESC
```

**EDIT** - as per comment: changed `UNION` to `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Yahia... May i add to this that it's good idea to use UNION ALL so database won't have to do extra work to check for duplicates (since there are no duplicates values in this example, each player has only one team_id).

Answer (score 1):

This may not be easily optimized, but it should work for any number of teams.

```
SELECT Player_ID, Team_ID, Player_name, Player_points, Player_status
FROM Players
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Players AS p
    WHERE p.Team_ID = Players.Team_ID
      AND p.Player_points > Players.Player_points
) <= 5
ORDER BY Team_ID ASC, Player_points DESC, Player_status DESC
```